# How to write integration/e2e tests for NestJs apps that use GRPC?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, grpc

I have a NestJs application that uses GRPC for the communication between microservices, and I have to write some integration tests/e2e tests for some of the endpoints (only mocking external calls to other microservices/clients, database calls, etc). However, the NestJs Docs only explains how to write integration tests for apps that use REST (see it [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#end-to-end-testing)).

This is the `.controller` file:

```
import {
  ClassSerializerInterceptor,
  Controller,
  Logger,
  UseFilters,
  UseInterceptors,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { GrpcMethod } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { RpcValidationFilter } from '../../common/exception/filters/rpc.filter';

enum GrpcService {
  NAME = 'TestService',
}

export class TestDto {
  userId: string;

  constructor() {
    this.userId = 'userId';
  }
}

@Controller()
@UseFilters(RpcValidationFilter)
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
export class TestController {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(TestController.name);

  constructor() {}

  @GrpcMethod(GrpcService.NAME)
  public testProto(data: TestDto): Promise<TestDto> {
    this.logger.debug(data, 'Testing GRPC method call');
    return Promise.resolve(new TestDto());
  }
}
```

This is the `.proto` file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package testProto.v1;

service TestService {
  rpc TestProto (RequestDto) returns (ResponseDto);
}

message RequestDto {
  string user_id = 1;
}

message ResponseDto {
  string user_id = 1;
}
```

So I need to create an app instance, and send a GRPC request that will reach out to the controller method.
Just to make it simple, I have not added any service layer/database layer here.
Does anyone how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can find a sample here https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/integration/microservices/e2e/orders-grpc.spec.ts

In the e2e test you should start the application and create a GRPC client that can be used in the tests to call the GRPC methods:

```
describe('AppController (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;
  let client: any;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
      controllers: [TestController],
    }).compile();

    app = module.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();

    app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
      transport: Transport.GRPC,
      options: {
        package: ['protopackage'],
        protoPath: [join(__dirname, '../src/path-to-your/file.proto')],
      },
    });
    // Start gRPC microservice
    await app.startAllMicroservices();
    await app.init();
    // Load proto-buffers for test gRPC dispatch
    const proto = ProtoLoader.loadSync(
      join(__dirname, '../src/path-to-your/file.proto'),
    ) as any;
    // Create Raw gRPC client object
    const protoGRPC = GRPC.loadPackageDefinition(proto) as any;
    // Create client connected to started services at standard 5000 port
    client = new protoGRPC.protopackage.YourService(
      'localhost:5000',
      GRPC.credentials.createInsecure(),
    );
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await client.close();
    await app.close();
  });

  it(`GRPC call`, async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      client.testProto(
        {
          ...yourTestDtoParameters,
        },
        { ...metadata },
        (err, result) => {
          // Compare results
          expect(err).to.be.null;
          expect(result).to.eql('your-expected-result');
          // Resolve after checkups
          resolve(true);
        },
      );
    });
  });
});
```